# how to decrease dictionary items by one when item is added to the cart in python

Tags: python, dictionary

What I am trying to do is to create a function in python to add up the total price for items added to the cart, if the item is available in the stock dictionary. In the same time, if the item is available and added to the total, I want to decrease the number of items in that dictionary by the amount that was added to the cart.

I am completely stuck and I don't know how to move forward, please see below code:

```
stock = {
    "item1": 6,
    "item2": 0,
    "item3": 32,
    "item4": 15
}

prices = {
    "item1": 4,
    "item2": 2,
    "item3": 1.5,
    "item4": 3
}

def compute_bill(cart):
    total = 0
    for key in cart:
        if stock[key] > 0:
            total += prices[key] 
        return total
```

Comment: I expect that `compute_bill` is meant to return the total after iterating over all the items in the cart and not after only the first. That is, you should outdent `return total`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the assumption, not stated as part of the problem, that the value of the  cart dict is the count of items of that sort desired, I would write the code like this:

```
def compute_bill(cart):
    total = 0
    for key, value in cart.items():
        if 0 < value <= stock[key]:
            total += prices[key] * value
            stock[key] -= value
    return total
```

If you had these values for `stock`, `price`, and `cart`:

```
stock = {
    "item1": 6,
    "item2": 0,
    "item3": 32,
    "item4": 15
}

prices = {
    "item1": 4,
    "item2": 2,
    "item3": 1.5,
    "item4": 3
}

cart = {
    "item1": 8,
    "item2": 3,
    "item3": 10,
    "item4": 10
}
```

then here is the price of the cart:

```
>>> print compute_bill(cart)
45.0
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(stock)
{'item1': 6, 'item2': 0, 'item3': 22, 'item4': 5}
```

Notice that item1 did not diminish because the order could not be filled in its entirety. Similarly, item2 was out of stock and not filled. And the buyer has 10 each of item3 and item4. The stock of both those items is diminished 10 items.

Also, this avoids the [negative cart quantity bug that Amazon had](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-hxX_Q5CnaA).

Comment: Thanks, how would you call this function and print it?

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This is amazing. I wish I'd know this stuff like you do. I am just learning it now, I started a couple of weeks ago. Thanks again.

Comment: Now I am wondering how I can set this up in a way that the cart items will be determined based on user input. Should I ask this as a new question? I actually would like to figure this out my self but I would appreciate if you could give me some pointers so I will at least understand the basic concept of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply reduce the stock count for that item:

```
def compute_bill(cart):
    total = 0
    for key in cart:
        if stock[key] > 0:
            total += prices[key] 
            stock[key] -= 1
        return total
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought also but I am wondering if I return total only, will this still return the decrease in the stock[key]? The best way to check would be if I complete the code and print it I guess but I am still trying to figure out how to do that, I am just learning python so still a little lost

Comment: @JoeRay, This will still decrease the stock numbers. Just because you don't return it doesn't mean you didn't decrease the value. Like you said. Try printing the stock before and after to get a sense of what happens. Glad I could help.